# Simplifying $ \cos(4\pi a)+\cos(4\pi b) + \cos(2\pi(a+b))\\ +\cos(2\pi(2a+b))+\cos(2\pi(a+2b))+\cos(4\pi(a+b)), $

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to simplify the following expression
$$
\cos\left(4\pi a\right)+\cos\left(4\pi b\right) + \cos\left(2\pi\left(a+b\right)\right)\\ +\cos\left(2\pi\left(2a+b\right)\right)+\cos\left(2\pi\left(a+2b\right)\right)+\cos\left(4\pi\left(a+b\right)\right),
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

I've played around with some trigonometric identities, but can't seem to find a good way to simplify it, if there's one at all.

Comment: Would the first term happen to be $\cos(2\pi a)$, or the second term $\cos(4\pi b)$, so that the expression is symmetric in $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry, $\cos(2\pi b)$ should actually be $\cos(4\pi b)$ please check again

Comment: It does not simplify. It is a Fourier series with six frequencies in general.